# On-disk structures for Files-11 format (RSX11)

Tags: hard-disk, file-format, dec, pdp-11

I'm looking for an explanation, or a link to documentation of the on-disk structures of the [Files-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11) format, that is, the format of disks used by [RSX-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSX-11) on the PDP-11. Also known as *ODS-1*, the precursor of the VMS format.

I've read that it was "published on the RSX SIG tapes a couple of times". That seem to be the tapes that are available under *decus* in a number of places, but I couldn't find the correct tape for that so far.

Comment: Is this a version of it: https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_decpdp11rspr81_1746551?q=files-11

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of files at http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11/, e.g.

Andrew C. Goldstein, *Files-11 On-Disk Structure Specification*, First Edition, Digital Equipment Corporation, 19 June 1975

at

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11/Files-11_ODS-1_Spec_Jun75.pdf

Andrew C. Goldstein, *Files-11 On-Disk Structure Specification*, Revised Edition, Digital Equipment Corporation, 15 June 1977

at

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11/Files-11_ODS-1_Spec_Jun77.pdf

and

Andrew C. Goldstein, *Files-11 On-Disk Structure Specification*, Revised Edition, Digital Equipment Corporation, 15 April 1981

at

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11/Files-11_ODS-1_Spec_Apr81.pdf

Do any of these help?

Comment: Thanks for the useful links. However, this answer is not complete (please read the [tour] to get a feel for how the site works). If you [edit](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/1968/edit) your answer to add enough information to it to answer the question (you can copy stuff from the links you provided, so long as you say where it's from), it will help a lot and your answer will (probably) be upvoted.

Comment: You are correct. But the description takes 35 pages. Would it fit here?

Comment: There's also an official y2k fix :-) https://manx-docs.org/collections/antonio/dec/MDS-2000-01/cd1/BLITZ/TD2735.PDF